# Waiting for elements to load does not work until I pause the script for few seconds

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

Using Selenium webdriver with java

Example we have lot of fields like the image below
I tried using explicit wait like 
i) waiting for elements to load (but the elements are dynamically loaded and does not populate until i click and wait for couple of seconds)
but does not work until I pause for couple of seconds.
I am using the below method

I am creating a framework and wanted to know if in other organisations programmers do use similar methods to pause the script or is it not used ?  because I need to use it so much.
[image]

Using below method as I did not want to use Thread.sleep courtesy stack overflow.

```
public static void customewait(int seconds){
     Date start = new Date();
     Date end = new Date();
     while(end.getTime() - start.getTime() < seconds * 1000){
         end = new Date();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use waits provided by selenium as following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("idOfElement")));
```

This code will wait for element to be visible for 5000ms and when it finds that element it initializes the object.

5000 is timeout time in milliseconds (ms)

you can read more at [this link](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html)

Comment: welcome @BretA, if this helped you achieve what you were trying you can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

**Thread.sleep** will stop the execution of the thread for the given time while **Webdriver wait** only waits till the mentioned condition is not met. So, the Best practice is to use web driver wait.

```
By ByLocator = By.xpath("Any XPath");
int seconds = 5 * 1000; // seconds in milli.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(ByLocator));
```

Comment: Thanks , i have to enter a input in the text field and the list of program managers loads dynamically in the example above. if i enter zoe in the text input the list of program managers with name zoe appears in the list  xpath'//span[@class='select2-results']/ul/li'      the code moves to next line and clicks enter button before the list is loaded without Thread.sleep